# If "eng mit" means "closely related," why would it be necessary to add the verb "zusammenhängen?"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Occasionally I spend time with [**Duolingo's Immersion feature,**](http://duolingo.wikia.com/wiki/Immersion) which allows users to try their hand at translating any number of documents.  The other night I submitted a translation for a sentence that two other users had already submitted translations for.  Both of them added a word to the translation that didn't seem necessary to me, but since I am not fluent in German, I've been wondering if it might be necessary after all.  Below I have listed the English sentence followed by the three translations.  The word that seems unnecessary to me has been bolded:

> It* deals with economic warfare such as the blockade of Germany, and with some issues closely related to the economy, such as military issues of transportation.

**Translation #1:**

> Sie befasst sich mit dem Wirtschaftskrieg wie die Blockade Deutschlands und mit einigen Problemen, die eng mit der Wirtschaft **zusammenhängen** wie militärische Transportfragen.

**Translation #2:**

> Sie befasst sich mit dem Wirtschaftskrieg wie die Blockade Deutschlands, und mit einigen Problemen, die eng mit der Wirtschaft **zusammenhängen** wie militärische Ausgaben des Transportes.

**Translation #3 (my translation):**

> Sie befasst sich mit dem Wirtschaftskrieg wie die Blockade von Deutschland und mit einigen Problemen die eng mit der Wirtschaft wie militärischen Fragen des Transportes.

**"It" refers to "the economic history of World War I."*

Up until recently, I've been limiting myself to just the translation of words and short phrases, but want to start challenging myself a bit more with full sentences.  Seeing translations that don't quite make sense to me question my ability to do a decent job of it.

I actually attempted to contact one of the other translators, but have not received any word back, so I thought I'd present this here to see if anybody in this community can explain why these other translators added the word **zusammenhängen.**

Comment: Where do you get the idea that _eng mit_ means “closely related” as such? Literally, it just means “close[ly] with”, which would also need a verb (participle) to make proper sense in English.

Comment: In my opinion, none of the translations is entirely correct, though. It should be ... _wie **der** Blockade_ and _militärische**n** Transportfragen_.

Comment: Good question, @JanusBahsJacquet.  I'm pretty sure I've seen an example of it somewhere before.  I'll hunt around to see if I can find some examples.  In the meantime, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I actually found a bunch of them.  I'll include a couple of them here and then add a link to the others: "Das ist eine große Kultur, die auch **eng mit** unserer eigenen verbunden ist." ("This is a great civilisation and one that is **closely related** to our own."), "Du bist genauso **eng mit** ihm verwandt wie er, und was kriegst du?" ("You're as **closely related** to him as he is, and what did you get?").  Others can be found at this link here: [**eng mit.**](http://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/eng+mit)

Comment: "eng" just means tight, narrow. Related in that phrase comes from "verbunden". I'd translate that as "tightly coupled'.  The other way around I'd translate "closely related" into German as "nahe verwandt".

Comment: @Lisa Ah, but those also have participles: _verbunden_ and _verwandt_.

Comment: 'Zusammenhängen' is the verb in thi sentence, so you cannot omit it.

Comment: It should be “wie **der** Blockade Deutschlands”. But the beginning of the sentence does not really work anyway, as “der Wirtschaftskrieg” is only one thing and therefore cannot have examples.

Comment: @Burki The verb in the English sentence is "deals (with)," which, in German is "befasst (sich mit)."  It isn't "related to" (zusammenhängen).  Please see comments I made to Beta below.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Very interesting observations.  I'm still a bit in the dark on why zusammenhängen is needed, but your comment was very illuminating and perhaps a close review of those sentences will bring me to my "Aha!" moment.  Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @CarstenS Thank you for your comment.  With a rep of 9,647, (which is amazing) you surely must know German rather well, so I want to see if I understand the reason it should be "wie der Blockade Deutschlands."  In English, "economic warfare" is a direct object of "deals with."  "Such as the blockade of Germany" is an adjectival phrase describing "economic warfare."  So, because "mit" requires dative case, the nouns in the adjectival phrase must be in dative case, too, correct?  That makes sense to me, but I want to make sure I've got that right.

Comment: @CarstenS I am assuming I can also translate "... the blockade of Germany ..." as "der Blockade von Deutschland," ja?

Comment: @CarstenS  Regarding your comment: _the beginning of the sentence does not really work anyway, as “der Wirtschaftskrieg” is only one thing and therefore cannot have examples._  This is really perplexing because it makes perfect sense in English.  In fact, just about any singular entity can have multiple examples.

Comment: For example, "food" is a singular entity, but there are many examples of food; a "flower" is a singular entity but we have many examples of a flower.  In the same way, "economic warfare" is a singular entity that can have many different forms.  There is no one type of economic warfare -- it can be a blockade, blacklist, obstruction of a supply line, etc.

Comment: @CarstenS You seem to really know German, so perhaps you're commenting on a particular aspect/feature of German that requires such a concept/sentence to be written a bit differently.  For example, in German is it necessary to add what does not exist in English and in this case does the translation need to be something like "It deals with _**(types of)**_ economic warfare ...?"

Comment: @Lisa Think of it this way: your translation literally says, “and with some issues that closely with the economy”; that is not grammatical in English either. The original English version has a _reduced relative clause_ (i.e., “issues closely related to” is a reduced form of “issues which are related to”). This reduction does not really work in German, where you write out the entire relative clause—including the verb. What you did was add _die_ (‘which’), but no verb. In English the verb is _is [related]_; in German it could be _zusammenhängen_ or, more directly, _[verbunden] ist_. But ->

Comment: -> it has to be _something_, otherwise you've got a clause with a relative marker/subject but no verb. And that's ungrammatical in both English and German. _Eng mit_ isn't really a syntactic unit at all: _eng_ as an adverb modifies the verb (and thus requires there to be one), while _mit [object]_ heads a prepositional phrase that is a complement of the verb. It may be easier to see this if you split them up: _einigen Problemen, die [mit der Wirtschaft] [eng zusammenhängen]_. If you remove the verb there, you end up with _eng_ ‘close[ly]’ dangling alone at the end, making no sense.

Comment: I am just a native speaker. I think it is the definite singular article that bothers me together with *wie*. I do not know if other native speakers would agree with me. Does the English sentence still sound perfectly fine to your if you replace *economic warfare* by *the economic war*?

Comment: And your analysis of why I think that dative is necessary is correct.

Comment: @CarstenS I hate to give you an answer like this, but regarding "economic war" vs. "economic warfare," "economic war" just sounds really odd to my ear in this sentence. (I am a native speaker of American English.) The word "war" tends to refer to "armed conflict" in general whereas "warfare" refers more specifically to the "waging of war."  I don't know that the two terms are always interchangeable.

Comment: The following elaborate a bit more: [**War**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/war#English) / [**Warfare**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/warfare) / [**What's the difference between "war" and "warfare"?**](https://www.italki.com/question/56769?hl=en-us)  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that German does not make a distinction between "war" and "warfare."  Is this correct?

Comment: @CarstenS TY for breaking down my translation a bit more. I see where the problem is. I see the reduced relative clause now. Your answer, combined with the ones from Janus have helped me understand why the sentence requires "zusammenhängen." Trying to learn German through example sentences at Reverso has been helpful, but clearly it can get a bit tricky with a language like German. I'm going to subject myself to some remedial training before moving forward with translation. In the meantime, TY all for helping me understand German sentence structure a bit better.  It has been enlightening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the English sentence, the subordinate clause

> and with some issues *closely related* to the economy

uses an adverb and participle construction to express the closeness.  You could also maintain the view that the the verb has been omitted and the phrase would then be:

> and with some issues *that are* closely related to the economy

In the German translation another route has been chosen, with a verb construction in the present tense *mit [etwas] eng zusammenhängen,* which is a fixed phrase, and you simply need the *zusammenhängen.* Your last example is not possible; you need to have a verb in this subordinate clause. *Eng mit [etwas] sein* is another construction with the use of *eng mit,* but still you need a verb.

Another translation, without a verb, may be closer to the original, but less idiomatic German would perhaps be:

> Sie befasst sich mit dem Wirtschaftskrieg, wie der Blockade Deutschlands und mit einigen Problemen mit engen Beziehungen zur Wirtschaft, wie Militärtransportfragen.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.  I have a question, though.  The sentence above just has one verb/predicate -- befasst.  The sentence is really saying, "It deals with ________ and with __________."  The clause that begins "and with" is merely an extension of "it deals with ...."  I guess you could say it is a sentence with two direct objects described by adjectival phrases.

Comment: In other words, [**it isn't a compound sentence having a subject and predicate in each.  It's a complex sentence with one subject, one predicate, and a couple of clauses tacked on to it.**](http://www2.ivcc.edu/rambo/eng1001/sentences.htm)

Comment: The only clause in that sentence that can stand alone is, "It deals with economic warfare such as the blockade of Germany" and the phrase "closely related to the economy" is really just an [**adjectival phrase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) describing "issues."  Is a verb/predicate in that clause required even if none exists in English?

Comment: I hope you don’t find my question aggravatingly hairsplitting, but I do want to make sure I get a solid grasp of what must be required for the German sentence. As a beginner, I really try to stick pretty closely to the text, to include sentence structure, as much as is possible.

Comment: If I could, I’d write to you in your language, but I’m afraid your English is far better than my German. It might make for a difficult read. So, thank you for having learned English so well and using it to help us in this forum.

Comment: @Lisa  Your comments prove that you have read and understood what I tried to explain. Translation is not a matter of merely transferring a text word for word into another langauge. Moreover, you have to make it sound like a natural way of saying or writing a sentence or a phrase in the new language, i.e. an idiomatic translation. All to often when you read a translated text, you can smell the original language in the translation, and that you do not want.

Comment: @Lisa, “und mit einigen eng mit der Wirtschaft zusammenhängenden Problemen” is also possible.

Comment: @Beta I am flattered that you think I understand.  I'm not quite sure that I do yet.  And though I do understand how a translated sentence can be grammatically correct but not sound natural, my German is at a level where I'll be content if it's just grammatically correct.  In other words, I'm okay if you can see the [**Angleutsch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denglisch) (or as you so cleverly put it "smell the original language”) in my translation(s) for now.  (I can hear German grammarians gasping already.)

Comment: Once I become more familiar with the language/build a stronger vocabulary, I can begin to weed that out. Put another way, I'm striving for production, not perfection.  I know some would admonish me for doing so, believing bad habits might be hard to unlearn, but it is a method that appeals to me.

Answer (score 3):

Translation #1 is the best one. You definitely need zusammenhängen, #3 misses a verb. Also I would replace Problemen with Themen. Issues is a very mighty noun, it can be translated to Probleme, Themen, Tatsachen, etc.

Comment: I am in accordance with you regarding Translation #1, but as for #3, I have a question about the sentence structure (see the comment I make to @Beta above).  And your comment about Problemen and Themen?  Very useful.  I just now reviewed several sentences using both and I can see the slightly different contexts in which they are used. Thank you for making that suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

"Eng mit" would be more like "close to", as "eng mit" does not contain a verb